# iPhone 6 low on storage and becoming non-functional

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a 64gb iPhone 6. I've been butting up to my local storage limit for a while now but yesterday all my photos disappeared and most of not all of the apps on the phone no longer open. I've deleted several very large apps, but every time I do the available storage only goes up temporarily before getting very low again. I've been able to open a couple apps now but still no photos (the app never even opens). I've tried syncing to computer but it doesn't recognize any photos on the device. This happened once this summer but only lasted for a few hours. This is well past the 24 hour mark. I would prefer to back up the photos before going the nuclear option of restoring it. Any ideas of what I could try would be appreciated?

Comment: Afaik, photos don't sync from the phone, only to the phone. You back them up to Photos. (Note: I don't use any cloud service so this is for phone/computer only)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming here that you have synced your phone to a Mac or PC and continue to do so? If so and you have the options in iTunes checked to sync photos (on a Mac it would be photos.app and on Windows it is usually a folder in your Pictures folder) you should be able to verify that they *are* on your computer.

Once you have found your missing photos and verified all you need is safely on your computer I would do a wipe and restore. That cleans out temporary/cached files and files left over from deleted apps and the like. To be safe I would make another backup of your phone on your local computer. And I would password protect the backup so it preserves any passwords saved on your phone. Once that is done...

On the phone it is in Settings > General > Reset > Erase All Content And Settings.

Erase the phone and then restore it from the backup you just made. That, in itself, may clear enough space on your phone to help the issue. If not you may have to remove some apps, music or photos to clear more space.